# Javascript query returning '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, sharepoint-2010

I've got a JavaScript file which is querying a SharePoint list. The column type is a Choice column called Devicetype and instead of returning the information list it returns [object Object] as shown in the screen grab.

I'm wondering if it's the var query string?

```
var query = "http://collaboration-dev.norgine.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?$expand=LifeCycleStatus&$filter=Id eq " + window.DeviceId + "";
```

It returning the results to a HTML file which I've included below the JavaScript.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGEp1.png)

```js
function getDeviceDetails() {
  var txtTitle = "";
  var txtOverview = "";
  //var txtAccessories = "";
  var txtDeviceType = "";
  var tempLCS2 = "";
  var query = "http://collaboration-dev.norgine.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?$expand=LifeCycleStatus&$filter=Id eq " + window.DeviceId + "";

  var call = $.ajax({
    url: query,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }
  });

  call.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
      var tempID = item.Id;
      var tempTitle = item.Title;
      //var LifeCycleStart = item.DeviceAvailableFrom  //moment
      //var LifeCycleStart = moment(item.DeviceAvailableFrom, "MM-DD-YYYY");

      var date = item.DeviceAvailableFrom;
      //var LifeCycleStart = moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');

      var LifeCycleStart = String.format('{0:dd}-{0:MM}-{0:yyyy}', new Date(item.DeviceAvailableFrom));
      //var LifeCycleStart=new Date();
      //LifeCycleStart.toString('dddd,MMM,yyyy');
      var LifeCycleStatus = item.LifeCycleStatusValue;
      var DeviceOverView = item.Description;
      //var AccessDetails = item.Accessorries;
      var DeviceKind = item.Devicetype;
      txtTitle = "<p>" + LifeCycleStart + "</p><p>" + LifeCycleStatus + "</p>";
      txtOverview = "<p>" + DeviceOverView + "</p>";
      //txtAccessories = "<p>" +  Accessorries + "</p>";
      txtDeviceType = "<p>" + DeviceKind + "</p>";
    });
    $('#devicedetails').append($(txtTitle)); //moment
    $('#deviceoverview').append($(txtOverview));
    $('#devicekind').append($(txtDeviceType));
    //$('#deviceacc').append($(txtAccessories));
  });

  call.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
  });
}
```

```html
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
<head>
  <script src="/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/sites/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/getDevices.js"></script>
  <script src="/sites/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/getDeviceDetails.js"></script>
  <script src="/sites/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/getDeviceKnownIssues.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function parseQueryString(queryString) {
      var params = {},
        queries, temp, i, l;
      queries = queryString.split("&");
      for (i = 0, l = queries.length; i < l; i++) {
        temp = queries[i].split('=');
        params[temp[0]] = temp[1];
      }
      return params;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      function getDeviceID() {
        if (typeof parseQueryString === "function") {
          if (window.location.href.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
            var qs = parseQueryString(window.location.href.split("?")[1])
            window.DeviceId = qs.did;
            getDeviceDetails();
            getDeviceKnownIssues();
          }
        }
      }

      getDeviceID();
      getDevices();
    });
  </script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  .tg {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }

  .tg td {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border- style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: normal;
  }

  .tg .tg-yw4l {
    vertical-align: top
  }
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
      <h1>Devices</h1>
      <div id="devices">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
      <h1>Device Details</h1>
      <div id="devicedetails">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
      <h1>Device Overview</h1>
      <div id="deviceoverview">
        <div id="devicekind">
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
      <h1>Accessories</h1>
      <div id="deviceacc">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
      <h1>Typical Usage</h1>
      <div id=" ">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">
      <h1>Another Table</h1>
      <div id=" ">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <xml>
    <mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
    <mso:_dlc_DocId msdt:dt="string">ITDOCUMENTS-135-47</mso:_dlc_DocId>
    <mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid msdt:dt="string">1d6007ea-9e58-4298-b2d6- 
    9196e2678ea3</mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid>

    <mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl msdt:dt="string">http://collaboration- 
      dev.norgine.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?  
       ID=ITDOCUMENTS-135-47, ITDOCUMENTS-135-47</mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl>
    </mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
  </xml>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: `$('#devicedetails').append(txtTitle); //moment
$('#deviceoverview').append(txtOverview);
$('#devicekind').append(txtDeviceType);` You should use `$().append()` without the $-operator as a paramter.

Comment: Right, so the line should be: $('#devicekind').append); ?

Comment: Just `$('#devicekind').append(txtDeviceType);` since `txtDeviceType` is a string with build in HTML attributes. So just pass the variable itself to the jquery object's append function

Comment: Thanks, that still returns [object Object]

Comment: Try  `$('#devicekind').append(txtDeviceType[0]);` !

Comment: Cheers, that returns ' < ' and if I change the [0] to [1] randomly  returns 'p'

Comment: Ok so can you check what's in the variable by using `console.log(txtDeviceType);` and/or `console.log(txtDeviceType[0]);` ?

Comment: No problem, just by adding a one of those lines in the code?

Comment: Yep, it seems like your data is corrupt. It would be better if you could add `console.log(DeviceKind);` **after** this line `var DeviceKind = item.Devicetype;`

Comment: If I add this:  var DeviceKind = item.Devicetype;
                    console.log(txtDeviceType);   

it takes all the results out of the Device Details and Device Overview columns

Comment: No you should have added `console.log(DeviceKind);` after this line `var DeviceKind = item.Devicetype;` in your code!

Comment: Yes that's what I've done

Comment: You added `console.log(txtDeviceType);` instead of `console.log(DeviceKind);`

Comment: Cheers, sorry, yes changed that, so now I've added console.log(DeviceKind); after var DeviceKind = item.Devicetype; and it's doing the same thing knocking out the results for Device Details and Device Overview columns.

Comment: This cannot be true. Did you add/remove something else? `console.log()` just logs variables/text to the console it should not interrupt your code. Anyway, can you please share what your console is logging?

Comment: Results are coming back on the HTML but still just showing '<' for the device type

Comment: I've pressed F12 gone into the Console and can't see anything for the variable coming up.

Comment: Ok seems like the program never reached this line in your code then. Remove the console log statement which you added and add `console.log("Reached this line.")` to a line before it, to check in which line it stops running. Go on doing this, until the console logs `Reached this line.`

Comment: Every time I add a console.log line it's knocking out the results for Device Details and Device Overview columns

Comment: It's kinda hard helping you, since I don't know the format of your data. E.g. is `item.Devicetype` an array, object, string?

Comment: It's a choice column in a SharePoint list, and what it should return is 'Laptop'.

Comment: If I add a number to  $('#devicekind').append(txtDeviceType[0]); I can get a random letter and I don't know where it's coming from.

Comment: So it should content a string? Anyway try to replace this line `txtDeviceType = "<p>" + DeviceKind + "</p>";` with that line `txtDeviceType = "<p>" + DeviceKind.toString() + "</p>";`

Comment: Thanks, I still get '<'

Comment: Might it be down to the column type being a check box?

Comment: The answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

IT's something to do with the Content Type. If I change the column from Drop Down to Free Text and change $('#devicekind').append(txtDeviceType[0]);
to $('#devicekind').append(txtDeviceType); it returns the correct result.